# Not able to install rails active_storage with sequel-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sequel

I am trying to install active_storage with rails 5.2 and I am using sequel-rails gem instead of active record.
I am getting following error while performing 'rails active_storage:install'

> rake aborted! Don't know how to build task
>   'app:railties:install:migrations' (see --tasks)
>   /home/edmodo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:635:in
>   `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
>   /home/edmodo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/lib/tasks/activestorage.rake:7:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /home/edmodo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/edmodo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`
>   eval'
>   /home/edmodo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in
>   `' Tasks: TOP => active_storage:install:migrations

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: how are you trying to install `gem sequel-rails  ` ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed sequel gem by adding 'gem sequel-rails' in Gemfile and then I am trying to run 'rails active_storage:install' command.

Comment: did you run bundle install ? did you find any error in bundle install ? please mention in question that you are getting this error when you performing ` rails active_storage:install` command

Comment: I have run bundle install and there is no error for this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you currently cannot use Active Storage with Sequel, since it has a hard dependency on Active Record classes.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb#L9

You need to use an alternate solution to Active Store, like [Shrine](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine) or you need to use Active Record.